# SQL query that is insensitive towards non-latin characters?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, collation

Is there any way I can write a `select` query with `where` clause, that ignores non-latin characters?

For example there is Lithuanian character `Ė`, obviously the equivalent in latin character would be `E`. So is there anyway I can write a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `keyword` LIKE %E%;
```

And I want it to return all records that contain any of these characters: `E,Ė,Ę`, is there any way I can achieve this automatically with SQL (or even in PHP level)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what you've tried. You also don't say what character set (utf-8) and collation your `table` contains.  Those are the ways you control those things by default.

You could try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `keyword` COLLATE utf8_general_ci LIKE %E%
```

Or this

```
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `keyword` COLLATE utf8_lithuanian_ci LIKE %E%
```

I don't know if the second one will work for what you want, because I don't know Lithuanian.  Are  E, Ė, and Ę considered the same letter in the dictionary? If they are *not*, then the Lithuanian collation won't match them to each other.

If you do find that a particular collation works, you can alter your column to use that collation by default.

```
alter table `table`
  change `keyword` `keyword` collate utf8_lithuanian_ci
```

That's a good idea because then you have a chance of indexes speeding your search.

Comment: To be honest, I did not try anything, simply cause I had no idea what to even try or what to google for. Apart from hacking some solution with char map in PHP array. Anyway, the first query you suggested seems to do exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!